# XML values of the same attribute in different elements cannot repeat

Tags: xml, xsd

In my C# application I use an XSD file to validate XML files. Is there any way to include in XSD file a prevention from repeating values of the `Reference_number` attribute in different elements?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Items">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Reference_number" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:float" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use `xs:unique` to constrain `Reference_number` to be unique:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Items">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Reference_number" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:float" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="UniqueItemRefNum">
      <xs:selector xpath="Item" /> 
      <xs:field xpath="Reference_number" /> 
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Then, for example, the following XML will be valid:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="try.xsd">
  <Item>
    <Name>name1</Name>
    <Reference_number>r1</Reference_number>
    <Price>1.00</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Name>name2</Name>
    <Reference_number>r2</Reference_number>
    <Price>2.00</Price>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

**But the following XML will be invalid (notice duplicate `Reference_number`):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="try.xsd">
  <Item>
    <Name>name1</Name>
    <Reference_number>r1</Reference_number>
    <Price>1.00</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Name>name2</Name>
    <Reference_number>r1</Reference_number>
    <Price>2.00</Price>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Answer (score 3):

For that purpose, you should use an element key or an element unique.
something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Items">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Reference_number" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:float" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="referenceKey">
            <xs:selector xpath="Item"/>
            <xs:field xpath="Reference_number"/>
        </xs:key>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```